# Deformation with fixed ramification

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $f : X \to Y$ is a finite, surjective morphism of normal varieties.  I want to know about the space of first-order deformations of $X$ over $Y$ with fixed ramification, i.e. the deformations of $f$ with fixed target $Y$, such that the (set-theoretic) image of the ramification divisor $f(R_t)$ is constant.

I think that when $X$ and $Y$ are smooth, there are no such deformations: the normal sheaf $N_f$ is supported on the ramification divisor $R \subset X$ (Sernesi, "Deformations...", pg 171), and a deformation of $f$ forces the ramification to move too.  But I am not sure if I can dispense with the smoothness assumption (or indeed whether my question is well-posed without it?)

Comment: for curves, if you read french, you may find something relevant there : http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701680 p.47 §5.2.3 Déformations, versus déformations du diviseur de branchement.

Answer (score 4):

The moduli problem you are interested in is zero-dimensional in characteristic zero. (In this answer we will work over $\mathbb{C}$.)

Indeed, for all $d\geq 1$,  and all normal varieties $X$ and $Y$, the set of isomorphism classes of finite degree $d$ surjective morphisms $X\to Y$  ramified over a fixed closed subset $B\subset Y$  is finite. This follows from the fact that $\pi_1(Y^{an})$ is finitely generated. (The fact that $d$ is fixed is because you are deforming a **fixed** finite map $X\to Y$. Thus, $d$ equals $\deg(X\to Y)$.)

The fact that $\pi_1(S^{an})$ is finitely generated holds for any variety $S$ over $\mathbb{C}$; see SGA7.I Théorème 2.3.1 Expose II.

In case you are interested: there is a (small) difference in studying finite etale covers of a variety $U = Y\setminus D$ and studying finite surjective maps $X\to Y$ ramified only over $D$. Indeed, there is a fully faithful functor from the category of finite etale covers of $U$ to the category of finite   surjective morphism $X\to Y$ ramified only over $D$. (To $V\to U$ one associates the normalization of $Y$ in the "function field" of $V$.)  This functor is not essentially surjective (because you can sometimes extend a given $V\to U$ to a finite surjective map $X\to Y$ with $Y$ normal but $X$ non-normal. Think of a rational function on a nodel curve.)  However, if you stick to normal varieties, the category you are interested in is  indeed equivalent to the category of finite etale covers of $Y\setminus B$.

Comment: (Of course, in characteristic $p>0$ this module space can be very high-dimensional.)

Comment: Good point. I edited the answer.